# What's the issue with the if *var* == *int*: code where var is a variable and int is a number?

Tags: python

I've been trying some code and a part doesn't work. I'm quite new to this so I don't see what's wrong. The code was working before but now it's stopped working. The variable is 'key' and the integer is 0.

```
if key==0:
  key=randint(1,72)
  print 'Your key is', key
```

The if key==0: plays up. This is the expected output:

```
Please select a key or type 0 to generate one. (1-71) '0'
Your key is 54
```

The 54 is representing the randomly generated number.
I've put all the correct tab lines in, but it just won't work.
It's worked for other sections of the code like the one below.

```
if key>71:
  print 'This is an incorrect key. Please select another.'
```

The code to produce this is:

```
key=int(input('Please select a key or type 0 to create one. (1-71)'))
```

Comment: Please update your question with the reason 'it doesn't work'

Comment: Show the code which is not working and the expected output.

Comment: btw you should really try to upgrade to python3 now that python2 is at end of life..

Comment: I think I should. You're correct quamrana.

Comment: You now show some expected output: `Please select ... `. Please show the code that produces this line.

Comment: Is that the right line of code? Did you mean: `key = int(input('Please select a key or type 0 to create one. (1-71)'))`?

Comment: Im working with Python 3

Comment: actually you're correct lol

Comment: How can that be so? Your code doesn't have parentheses in the call to `print()`.